# Exporting and importing techniques javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I have created absolute pathing in my application like @components etc. and I also have created index.js in components directory that basically contains exports of all components like

```
export * from "./navbar"
export * from "./tabs"
```

and I import them like so

```
import {navbar,tabs} from "@components"
```

And i have implemented it in all application like in screen , utils and other directories.
I am concerned about performance issues that is there any performance issue can exists there or it is noting to do with performance like so. and this is good technique for readability and single source of importing.

Comment: These imports exist only in build time. There is no difference in the final code which is run by the browser.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski so its ok to follow this pattern. or any other better suggestion .

Comment: Looks fine to me